# NSMenu - dynamically adding NSMenuItem and Menus recursively

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmenuitem, nsmenu

I need to create a tree structure for NSMenu using data like

01.level1:01.level2.1:01.level3.1#123456

01.level1:01.level2.2:02.level3.2#622112

01.level1:02.level2.3#98798

rootMenuItem -> level1 ->level2.1 ->level3.1 (on click 123456 has to be printed)

```
                              ->level3.2 (on click 622112)

                   ->level2.3(on click 98798)
```

Like this we need to build 'n' level structure based on data obtained.

As of now I am able to add menuitem to menu recursively from last leaf to 1st level but unable to check the similar labels/names in previous levels and build a unique tree hierarchy as in NSBrowser.

Sine NSMenu delegates are not efficient as NSBrowser delegates, trying to achieve the same using for/while loops recurively.

Logic which I tried is not working when trying to add a menu to another menu(since always menu can be added to another menuItem).
please let me know unique logic to achieve this task.  please help us

Thank you..